# Keycode for '^' (caret) in android java?

Tags: java, android, keycode, android-keypad

I am developing a Simple calculator for android platform. I am using my own custom keyboard layout. To  set a KeyPressed Event, I use the following code:

```
tv1.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0));
```

After googling all the android resources like:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

I couldn't find the KeyCode for caret symbol. Is there any keycode for that symbol?

Comment: @MrEngineer13 Can you suggest any method  to find the keycode for ^

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.d("KeyCode", "" + keyCode);
        }
    });
```

Attach that to an edit text.

Then, just go to logcat and see which keyCode comes up when you hit `^`

Comment: Sorry.This is not giving me a value @styler1972